# automatically copy the selected content to clipboard

Tags: x11, gnome-terminal, clipboard, terminal-emulator

In one of my friend's system I have seen a very interesting feature. Whenever he selects a text/command from the terminal, the selected portion of text gets copied to clipboard automatically (without right click + copy). He then presses (Shift+Insert) to paste it somewhere else.

How can I implement the same in my system. I am running Ubuntu Mate 15 version.

Comment: And what is your friend running ? e.g. this feature is by default when using `putty`

Comment: There are also some minimal terminal emulators that implement this by default - mrxvt or st come to mind.

Comment: I thought this was the default behaviour. I've had this in all Unices I've run since 1992...

Comment: @Kusalananda presumably you’re used to pasting using middle-click (from the primary selection), not with Shift+Ins or Ctrl+V ;-).

Comment: @StephenKitt Ah, that's true. I was ignoring the pasting bit with the keys. Right-click + copy is something I've only had to use in Windows terminals though.

Answer (score 1):

Try installing `parcellite`.

Your question has an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3348800/gnome-terminal-how-to-copy-selection-to-clipboard-automatically)

Answer (score 1):

If using Cinnamon DE, you can simply paste the highlighted/selected text by doing a middle click. You can check if it works on Mate too.

Comment: It depends on the application (more precisely, on the GUI toolkit it uses), not on the desktop environment. It works in most.

Comment: Even works in pure console if you have gpm installed and running.  And, if you don't have a wheelie mouse (ie, laptop w/ 2 buttons) you can click both at once to get the same effect.

Answer (score 1):

Comes for free with the xfce4-terminal that should be possible to install (maybe addtionally) wherever you want

Comment: I always thought so too ... but in recent installs of Xubuntu I have to check the option for this (i.e., in the terminal window under *Edit* | *Preferences*)